# How do I match zero or more brackets in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want a python regex to capture either a bracket or an empty string. Trying the usual approach is not working. I need to escape something somewhere but I've tried everything I know.

```
one = "this is the first string [with brackets]"
two = "this is the second string without brackets"

# This captures the bracket on the first but throws  
# an exception on the second because no group(1) was captured
re.search('(\[)', one).group(1)
re.search('(\[)', two).group(1)

# Adding a "?" for match zero or one occurrence ends up capturing an
# empty string on both
re.search('(\[?)', one).group(1)
re.search('(\[?)', two).group(1)

# Also tried this but same behavior
re.search('([[])', one).group(1)
re.search('([[])', two).group(1)

# This one replicates the first solution's behavior
re.search("(\[+?)", one).group(1) # captures the bracket
re.search("(\[+?)", two).group(1) # throws exception
```

Is the only solution for me to check that the search returned None?

Comment: I'd say you don't need the capturing group. Just see if `\[` matches or not. What should be the purpose of the capturing group anyway if the only thing that it can match is a single [.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You want to match a bracket or an empty string. The second input contains an empty string between each character, so it matches the empty string.

Comment: In general, optional items in a regular expression only make sense if they're before or after something else that you want to match. Searching for it by itself makes no sense -- if it's optional, the input will match whether it contains it or not.

Comment: Are you by any chance talking about returning the [`content`] of the brackets?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple! :

```
(\[+|$)
```

Because the only empty string you need to capture is the last of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach.

```
import re

def ismatch(match):
  return '' if match is None else match.group()

one = 'this is the first string [with brackets]'
two = 'this is the second string without brackets'

ismatch(re.search('\[', one)) # Returns the bracket '['
ismatch(re.search('\[', two)) # Returns empty string  ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the thing I wanted to do is to take a string and, if I find any square or curly brackets, remove the brackets and their contents from the string.
I was trying to isolate the strings that needed fixing first by finding a match and the fixing the resulting list in a second step when all I needed to do was do both at the same time as follows:

```
re.sub ("\[.*\]|\{.*\}", "", one)
```